# how do you build a bot for multiple people to use when you hardcode a token?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/slackhq/python-slackclient). In the examples, it uses a hardcoded token. If I wanted to put this app on the Slack marketplace, how do I dynamically "listen" to multiple app tokens using:

```py
token = "xoxp-28192348123947234198234"  # found at https://api.slack.com/web#authentication
sc = SlackClient(token)
if sc.rtm_connect():
    while True:
        print sc.rtm_read()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Do I need to make a new bot instance for every integration?

Comment: 1. *Don't* hard-code the token, make it available e.g. via an environment variable (see e.g. http://pythonhosted.org/aslack/aslack.html#aslack.utils.get_api_token for an example from a Python Slack project of my own). 2. And certainly don't post it publicly on SO.

Comment: can you stack the environment variable such that it supports multiple tokens? my question is essentially i want to use 1 bot instance for multiple tokens.

Comment: Then you need a list of tokens, which you can still provide via an environment variable, perhaps as a comma-separated string, or using e.g. a config file. You'll have to look into the implementation of `SlackClient` to determine whether/how you can use multiple tokens with it or whether you'll need one instance per token.

Comment: As I understand it your app goes through an authentication process each time a new user adds it to his Slack Team. During that authentication process you receive an individual token which you need to store and use for communication with that specific Slack Team.

Answer (score 2):

A token = a team. If you hardcode your token, it can be used only by the team who supplied the token. That would be typical for a custom integration, but it is not compatible with an app you'd release on the Slack directory.

A typical solution is to store each token in your database (using strong encryption!) and, indeed, fire a new bot RTM connection for each team.